# Authentication failed upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, authentication, 19.10

It's Kubuntu to be more precise. BTW my network works and i have tried to remove the 32bit architecture/packages.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,319 kB]                                                                                         
Fetched 1,320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                        
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg' 
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

EDIT: So what i did was to open sources.list and substitute "disco" with "eoan". It everything works so far after the upgrade.

Comment: I don't know what mirror you are using, but I'd suggest checking your chosen/used mirror is *up-to-date* (or only a few hours behind); https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors for if it's *last update unknown* especially  (counter on it's last update has overflowed!), that could be your problem, ie. use a maintained mirror.

Comment: Gonna try another mirror; right now seems like https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release is offline tho'.

Comment: Nope, i still get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[bentolor's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183912/2174) led me to a different command which seemed to ultimately fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring
```

I'm guessing this restores the keyring to defaults, something must have changed since the package was last installed. Now I can run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop` without the Authentication failed error.

Comment: Good, these replies are better then everything i found around the Internet.  Next time ima gonna try this.

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 upgrade as well.

Comment: I got a brand new Dell Precision with Ubuntu 18.04 and it has the error described here. OUT OF THE BOX!  This fix worked.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the exact same problem. The problem is a missing signing gpg key `871920D1991BC93C`. `apt-key adv --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C` *did not* solve the issue as the key doesn't seem to publicy available.

But

```
$ sudo apt-key update
Warning: 'apt-key update' is deprecated and should not be used anymore!
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:               imported: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

helped. After that I was able to start the upgrade. This was a very long-term installation continuously updated.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what [Bentolor said in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183912/63606), this command solved the problem for me:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C

Here is the reasoning behind the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1281413/63606