# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I have tried so many ways to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using command line as well as terminal.

In the GUI, it will return the error `Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server`.

When I did using `sudo do-release-upgrade` command it returned as "authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg'".

I'll attached the image as well and can anyone help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: You haven't given the command you are upgrading with, however I'd suggest checking your details. You mention 28.04 to 20.04, the path from 18.04 to 20.04 only opens after 20.04.1 has been released, and the picture you provide (please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste text into your question) only mentions *eoan* or 19.10 and not 20.04 so may not be what you want to do anyway (*or your description doesn't match your picture*).  Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is last month i upgraded ubuntu 18.04.4 to 19.10. I received a prompt informing me that I can upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10. After the upgrade there lot of issues came with software. Stuck the os and things. Then i'm downgrades back using command that I found in internet. Once it finished I got 18.04. Now there are set of issue. First one is can't open terminal. I have fixed few. But now I need to move stable version. Whats is the best option to do? Once I check  by "sudo do-release-upgrade" command. It showed me i have 19.10 update. cont

Comment: But when I proceed it I got "authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg' 
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.". Anyway I want to move stable release. Is there any better suggestion?

Comment: Tried this as well. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183095/authentication-failed-upgrading-from-19-04-to-19-10

Comment: I'm not sure what 'command' can downgrade a release; `apt` and like tools found in Ubuntu upgrade automatically to later versions, not backwards, so I'd be suspicious you didn't return to 18.04 (unless you restored backups or something you didn't mention) which explains why the 19.10/eoan is explained (ie. your release is now neither bionic/18.04 or eoan/19.10 but bits of each).  You haven't said if you're talking desktop or server, but I'd work out what you're actually running currently, as your description is very unclear.

Comment: The most stable release of the three (bionic/eoan/focal) is of course bionic.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS releases aren't offered the upgrade path until after 20.04.1 has been released (a number of days after the ISO release) to ensure stability, so 18.04 is currently deemed as the most stable, though technically all of bionic/eoan & focal are 'stable' (bionic is the just most stable).  Given I don't know what you're currently on (but suspect it's an unstable mess of eoan/bionic) I'd recommend a re-install (esp. if a desktop release), using 'something-else' & without formatting existing partitions.

Comment: Had the same problem and this helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1281412/600344