# do-release-upgrade -d authentication problem

Tags: gnupg, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 using

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

but I'm getting the following output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,344 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 2
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made Thu 03 Sep 2020 03:23:39 PM CEST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
gpg: Signature made Thu 03 Sep 2020 03:23:39 PM CEST using RSA key ID 991BC93C
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

I tried

```
apt-get install debian-keyring
```

and countless other advices that I found but nothing works. How can I upgrade?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before `do-release-upgrade -d` ?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem like the original poster and found out it was a missing (not logged) gpg key. For information my installed system is really old was updated through the years from a 13.10 installation so I guess that's why there were some public key problems.

First I checked the two files with `apt-key verify focal.tar.gz.gpg focal.tar.gz`

Which showed me that there was a key missing to check the signature.

In case you don't have this files in your `tmp` folder you can just download them and make the verification:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz.gpg

```
gpgv: Signature made jeu. 03 sept. 2020 15:23:39 CEST
gpgv:                using RSA key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) ftpmaster@ubuntu.com"
gpgv: Signature made jeu. 03 sept. 2020 15:23:39 CEST
gpgv:                using RSA key 871920D1991BC93C
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I then added the missing public key via: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C`

The update was functioning properly afterwards.

Comment: I've went through maybe fifteen answers, none of those worked. But this one did. Basically you can simply run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C` and it should do it.
Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

This system was upgraded from xenial some years ago. For some reason sources.list was not upgraded and still referred to xenial. I replaced it with the one found here https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1 and got an opportunity to upgrade many packages. There are still some conflicts but I guess that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did run into the same problem (running an old version of Xubuntu 18.04) and even updating the keyring ('apt-get install debian-keyring') did not help.
Due to the fact that the installation was very useless I tried to update some packages by hand:
'curl' (which was not able to use newer protocols than TLS1.1)
and started 'do-release-upgrade', expecting it to fail. But it only said that other things should be updated. So I ran
'sudo apt install snapd'
and started the release-upgrade.

Because that failed again (with messages related to "(appstreamcli:4382): GLib-ERROR" I did start

> > > sudo apt dist-upgrade

and NOW IT WORKS fine.